# Add an Optional Buffer to File Costing in Installshield

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I am writing an installer (Installshield 2013 basic MSI) for an application that has a rather large runtime disk space requirement (1.5 Gb). That space is used for a recording file that can be on any hard drive on the user's machine. At setup time, I would like the setup program to:

- Check if there is enough space for the recording file on the drive selected. If not, prevent installation and give the user the possibility to change the target drive. (this works)
- Check that there will be at least (some minimum space, say 500Mb ) left after installation. If not, suggest changing the target drive, and give the user the possibility to either change the target drive or proceed anyway. (This is where I struggle)

Is there any to figure out how much space would remain on one drive after the file costing? There does not seem to be any variable with this information in windows installer.

Example: 
Let's say the recording file is 1GB, and I want a 500Mb buffer. If there is

1. Less than 1 Gb free: Require the user to change target drive
2. Between 1Gb and 1.5: Warn the user, allow to change target drive OR proceed
3. Above 1.5Gb: Proceed with install.

What I did: I associated a ReserveCost element with my recording file component and it correctly handle cases 1 and 3 below. How do I handle case #2?

Answer (score 0):

This is what the Windows Installer's [ReserveCost Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371226(v=vs.85).aspx) is for.  MSI automatically calculates the cost but you can give it additional weight through this table.  To access this table in InstallShield use the direct editor.

Here's a half baked idea you might be able to expand on.   Perhaps you could create an optional "feature" that does nothing important except have a component that reserves 500mb of space.   Then maybe you could work out your UI experience to make it easy for your user to turn this on and off in order to have a way to recost and proceed with space available.

I'm not convinced I like this experience but it's the best I can think of for you.

Comment: This is what I do. But there is no way to figure out if there just isn't enough space (in which case the installation will fail, so we want to prevent the user from proceeding) or there is not enough buffer (in which case the user needs to be warned, but allowed to continue)

Comment: I can think of a number of ways to do this but I don't think I would.  It just makes the installer more complex and fragile.  I would just install the application and then handle data file location and space requirements in the application itself.

Comment: Remember, directories are immutable in Windows Installer once set.  So if you install a DATADIR component you are stuck unless you uninstall / reinstall.   Punting to the application eliminates that problem.